# Discrete subgroups of $O(2)$ are all finite.

Tags: group-theory

How to prove that discrete subgroups of the orthogonal group in dimension $2$ are all of finite order?

Please help me in this regard. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to note that $O(2)$ is compact.

Suppose that $G$ is an infinite subgroup of $O(2)$.  Then $G$ contains an infinite sequence $(g_k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$.  Because $O(2)$ is compact, this sequence contains a convergent subsequence, so suppose WLOG that $g_k \to g \in O(2)$.

Verify that the induced topology on $\{g_k\}_{k \in \Bbb N}$ is not the discrete topology.  In particular, note that any open subset of $O(2)$ containing $g$ must contain all but finitely many elements of the sequence.

Comment: You use Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. Right?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 for which part? To show that $O(2)$ is compact?

Comment: No. The part that $\{g_k \}$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: But how do I prove that $O(2)$ is compact?

Comment: By Heine-Borel, it suffices to note that $O(2)$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$

Comment: Yes. I agree with you.

Comment: Actually the map $A \mapsto AA^T$ from $M$ to itself is continuous, where $M$ is the set of all $2 \times 2$ matrices. $O(2)$ is the inverse image of the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix $I$ under that map. Since singleton sets in any metric space are closed so $O(2)$ is the inverse image of a closed set in $M \subset \mathbb R^4$ under a continuous map and hence $O(2)$ is closed. Also the Euclidean norm of every matrix in $O(2)$ is $\sqrt 2$. Since any two norms on $\mathbb R^4$ are equivalent so it follows that $O(2)$ is also bounded. Thus $O(2)$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: So by using Heine-Borel theorem it follows $O(2)$ is compact.

Comment: @Dbchatto I am glad to see you complete the proof in the comments! It's always good to see that.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Miller for your generous behaviour towards me.